# Resilience for WCF service hosted as windows service

Tags: wcf, windows-services

We have got WCF services one hosted as windows service (it uses MSMQ binding) and other hosted in IIS.
To have resilience we have got 7 servers where WCF is hosted on IIS, and the 3rd party tool randomly sends request to either of the servers.

How to achieve a similar functionality for WCF service hosted on windows service using MSMQ binding.

Answer (score 0):

If your 3rd Party tool also 'works' like NLB by itself having an additional IP and then randomly picking one of the clustered IPs then the below article should help:

http://devproj20.blogspot.com/2007/04/load-balancing-msmq.html

(Note that if you are using private$ queues then only one of the servers will actually receive the message, which should be correct)

Alternatively, you might look at using a (single) remote queue on a server and then find another way to manage the redundancy of the MSMQ storage?

HTH!